# Pycharm - MacBook - models.py is not recognized

Tags: django, django-models, pycharm

Look at this image:

[image: PyCharm]

I think is missing some setup config, because when I try to create my models.py happens this. The code is not recognized and the file is not like py files...

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Note: Is not a file type problem, because the another files code is recognized and the file icon is of python.

Comment: Is it saved ? does it do that even after saving ?

Comment: Yes, as you can see the file is saved... Crazy stuffs..

Comment: Did you try deleting models.py since it isn't a python file for some reason, and re-creating the models.py as a python file, then test?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I have no idea what is happening ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: Is not a file type problem, because the another files code is recognized and the file icon is of python.

**You are wrong -- it is File Types problem.**

1. **Preferences | File Types**
2. **Text Files** in upper list
3. Find and remove unwanted pattern in lower list -- I expect this to be `models.py` or quite similar

A bit more / simialr SO questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281563/783119
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11687851/783119