# pycharm: not recognizing local python files

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following files in a project folder (there are more; just listing what's relevant):

```
repo
|--> flask_app
    |--> app.py
    |--> helper_functions.py
```

If I try to import `helper_functions.py` inside of `app.py` the former is highlighted in red (however it does work when I run the script).

app.py:

```
import pandas  # works, no red highlight
import helper_functions  # works, red hightlight
```

Not sure what the problem is here. I realize it's not a huge deal because everything works fine; however, the red highlight is very distracting and it's hard to distinct true errors from this PyCharm glitch. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687302/pycharm-not-recognizing-python-files) but no luck.

Comment: only import statements are highlighted or python syntax too?

Comment: Python syntax too. So if I use a function from `helper_functions` that's highlighted in red as well

Comment: what interpreter is chosen in PyCharm settings?

Comment: 3.6.0 (~/anaconda/bin/python). This may be the reason. I just upgraded to python 3 over python 2 (I used to have 2.7.12 at the same location)

Comment: with old version everything works fine?

Comment: It did. I deleted the old version (python 2) and installed the new version. I also tried the `__init__.py` file and it didn't work

Comment: it looks like PyCharm couldn't properly set Python interpreter, first of all check one more time if it has been correctly specified for your project, then try invalidate caches/restart and if all of it doesn't help consider re-installing of Python interpreter from scratch

Comment: I'll give it a try in the next few days and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out. Because I'm working in a directory that isn't a direct child of the repository (e.g. it's a directory inside a child directory), I need to mark it (`flask_app` in this case) as a `Sources` Folder. Which tells Pycharm to look for imports when executing code from this folder.

To do this, simply go to Preferences > Project Structure > Click on the folder > Click on `Mark as: SOURCES`.

The red highlight disappears and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `__init__.py` file (may be empty) inside of your package, this helps to both Python and PyCharm to understand that you are working inside of Python package, not regular directory, [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Also it helps to mark your package as `Source Root`, more info about it can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/content-root.html)

Answer (score 0):

in VScode if is local file, but other folder opened, it's not recognize it