# python main.py turn to text file in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, text, pycharm, program-entry-point

I suddenly have a problem with file main.py .
I am using pycharm with python version 3.6 from anaconda.

I had a full project that run fine and now the 'main.py' became text file.
If I open a new project and name a new python file as 'main' it automatically turn into text file (any other name remains .py file).

What is the problem?

Comment: Any news on this front?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm not recognizing Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687302/pycharm-not-recognizing-python-files)

Comment: Same issue here, if I rename "main.py" to anything else it works fine....