# Different color text for key words in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

All the python code in my PyCharm editor is the same font color. How do I change the settings of PyCharm so that different key words in Python are different font colors? This should be very simple, but for some reason I can't figure it out.  I've tried so many different configurations in the color and theme settings but nothing works.

Here's what my editor looks like:

[image: Picture of what python code in my PyCharm looks like]

Comment: Go to "File->Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->Language Defaults->Semantic highlighting"

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/2782180

Comment: It looks like the editor isn’t recognizing the file as a Python file. Personally I think this is off-topic, try the JetBrain forums/support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm utils.py not getting syntax highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374533/pycharm-utils-py-not-getting-syntax-highlight)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm not recognizing Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687302/pycharm-not-recognizing-python-files)

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by others, it looks like the file is not recognized as a python file. Try going to File - Settings - Editor - File Types - Text Files and remove utils.py ([Pycharm utils.py not getting syntax highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374533/pycharm-utils-py-not-getting-syntax-highlight))

Try going to File - Settings - Editor - Color Scheme - Language Defaults. From there you can change the scheme you want. I personally use Monokai as it's easy on the eyes and it has nice color variety. There are also different fonts you can play around with in that area of the settings.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the screenshot in the OP, it seems that the file is not being recognized as a Python code file (look at the icon). Changing the settings for Python highlighting wouldn’t solve anything.